# How to add text to a canvas inside a button in kivy

Tags: python, canvas, text, kivy, kivy-language

So I am making the top of the frontend for my game and want to ask how do we add text to it?
This is a simple frontend coming at the top of my screen and I don't know how to add text to
it without making it flat so I want help to make sure that I can write text in any font and that the button stays round.

Here is my .kv code:

```
 BoxLayout:
     id: top_layout
     orientation: "vertical"
     spacing: 50

    GridLayout: 
        id: top_of_main_screen
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.9}
        size_hint: (1, 0.2)
        rows: 1
        cols: 6
        orientation: "lr-bt" 

        Button:
            id: left_empty_button
            background_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
            background_normal: ''
            size_hint: 0.5, 1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: (0, 0, 0, 0)
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    radius: [0, 0, 12, 0]
        
        Button:
            id: profile_button
            background_color: (0,0,0,0)
            background_normal: ''
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    radius: [0, 0, 12, 12]
            
        Button:
            id: leaderboard_button
            background_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
            background_normal: ''
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: (0, 0, 0, 1)
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    radius: [0, 0, 12, 12]
        
        Button:
            id: coins_button
            background_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
            background_normal: ''
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    radius: [0, 0, 12, 12]

        Button:
            id: cash_button
            background_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
            background_normal: ''
            Label:
                pos: root.pos
                size_hint: 1, 1
                text: "Coins"
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: (0, 0, 0, 1)
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    radius: [0, 0, 12, 12]
        
        Button:
            id: right_empty_button
            background_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
            background_normal: ''
            size_hint: 0.5, 1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: (0, 0, 0, 0)
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    radius: [0, 0, 0, 12]
```

An answer in kivy language would be appreciated. There is nothing in my .py code as of yet.

Comment: Try adding `text` and `font_name` to your `Button`.

Comment: Tyvm I am sorry for even asking such a question. I was trying to put a label inside the button lol.